# Intercommunication between JNLP(client) / Apache / Java program(server)

Tags: java, http, networking, web-applications, jnlp

I am practicing some web-apps technology. I setup Apache HTTP server which provides HTTP page with JNLP/FlashFX file with simple data-form to fill by the user. My first idea was to send/receive the data from JNLP with help of UDP (I just serialize object inside datagrams). To be more specific:

- Apache provides a static HTTP and JNLP/FlashFX (HTTP is just to deploy JNLP)
- JNLP communicates via UDP with server
- server runs simple Java program to send/receive UDP packets to JNLP

My problem is when I access the page from 'client' browser machine a firewall asking if I want to allow/deny the access to network from 'java'. No doubts this is normal, but I think no one is expecting this from a web page....  I want to change this approach and use existing HTTP protocol.

QUESTION UPDATE

As far as I understood with HTTP protocol we have couple of methods which are used to communicate with the server (GET, PUT, POST .... ) and provided by Apache service.

I would like to use this for data exchange like this:

- JNLP sends some serialized data with HTTP methods
- Apache will redirect some (or full) traffic to my Java program
- My Java program will answers via Apache to my JNLP

How can I do that?

Comment: This is the operating system asking whether the JVM executing your application should be allowed to use the network.

Comment: I corrected my question. My problem is to understand any possibilities to exchange data between the web-app and server in both directions.

Comment: What does this have to do with JNLP?  Is there a desktop app. in there somewhere?

Comment: Of course. This is more general question. I am not quite sure if JNLP here have some more communication possibilities than other solutions...

Comment: *"I am not quite sure if JNLP here have some more communication possibilities than other solutions"*  No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Andrew. You mentioned desktop app. This is exactly what I want to do. The separate desktop application on the server receiving data from my client, but with help provided by HTTP server. But now I am not sure what exactly Apache/JSP server could provide here, except serving my JNLP for browsers...

Comment: *"except serving my JNLP for browsers"*  The server needs to provide the correct mime-type for JNLP files.

Comment: @Andrew. Thanks for response. At some point I realized I need even more from server because I wish to use a REST for communication (so I need app-server like glassfish)... I clarified more in my head about HTTP last month, but this question is still open...